# CalendarEventSeries, missing setRecurrence() method?

Tags: google-apps-script

Google scripts doc states CalendarEventSeries should have at least **two** methods `setRecurrence()`. When I'm trying to use it:

```
setRecurrence(new Date(), CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addYearlyRule().interval(1));
```

I'm getting this error:

> Cannot find method (class)setRecurrence(object,$Proxy754). (line 60,
>   file "Sync").

The method is invoked on `CalendarEventSeries` for sure. How to resolve that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you show applies to [all day Events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_calendareventseries?hl=fr-FR#setRecurrence) (specifying only one date for the first occurrence), are you applying to such an event or to a 'normal' event ?

In this last case you should provide 2 dates (start and end) for the first occurrence.

The link above shows the documentation that is pretty clear about it...

Here is an "end-to-end" example that shows how it works, the first function creates an event with a yearly recurrence starting today, the second one changes this recurrence to be daily, starting today...

It uses your default calendar

```
function createTestSerie(){
  var cal = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar()
  if (cal) {
  var title = 'Test Event';
  var desc = 'Created using Google Apps Script';
  var loc = 'Here, there and everywhere...';
  var recur = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addYearlyRule().interval(1)
  var start = new Date();
  var end = new Date(start.valueOf()+3600*1000);

  var event = cal.createEventSeries(title, start, end,recur,{description:desc,location:loc});// event will be every year and last 1 hour
  }   
}

function modifyRecurrence(){
  var cal = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar()
  if (cal) {
  var start = new Date();
  var end = new Date(start.getTime()+3600*1000*2);
  var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("February 16, 2013 08:00:00 PDT"), new Date("February 19, 2013 08:00:00 PDT"))
    for(i in events){
     if(events[i].getTitle()=='Test Event'){
       var recur = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addDailyRule().interval(1)
       var eventId = events[i].getId()
       cal.getEventSeriesById(eventId).setRecurrence(recur, start, end);// now events will be lasting 2 hours evey day starting today
       }
   }
   }
}
```

**EDIT following your comment :**  It works exactly the same for allDayEvents, here is a modified example code :

```
function createAllDaySerie(){
  var cal = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar()
  if (cal) {
  var title = 'All Day Test Event';
  var start = new Date();
  var desc = 'Created using Google Apps Script';
  var loc = 'home';
  var recur = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addYearlyRule().interval(4)
  var start = new Date();
  var event = cal.createAllDayEventSeries(title, start,recur,{description:desc,location:loc});// event will be every 4 years starting today
  }   
}

function modifyAllDayRecurrence(){
  var cal = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar()
  if (cal) {
  var start = new Date("February 19, 2010 08:00:00 PDT");// here you can choose any date you like that will be the new start date.
  var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("February 16, 2013 08:00:00 PDT"), new Date("February 22, 2013 08:00:00 PDT"))
    for(i in events){
     if(events[i].getTitle()=='All Day Test Event'){
       var recur = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addYearlyRule().interval(1)
       var eventId = events[i].getId()
       cal.getEventSeriesById(eventId).setRecurrence(recur, start);// now events will occur once a year starting on february 19, 2010 (see screen capture below)
       }
   }
   }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for response, my case relates to a "birthday" datefield, which I've tried to move into calendar. So I'm talking about allday event starting at specified day in the past without any end date. I'm creating it using CreateAllDayEventSeries() which takes a name, start date and reccurence.

I would like then to just move this event series (meaning ALL events belonging to it) to another day... without any specified end date.

Does it make sense now?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I edited my response with a new example that corresponds to your use case

Comment: And now I'm confused. Your example worked. I must then check out what is wrong in my code :|

Answer (score 1):

And we have the solution for my problem. There is a bug in API documentation. It is written there:

```
method setRecurrence(startDate, recurrence)
Changes the recurrence rules of this series to a new rule, and to an all day event.
```

But in fact method setRecurrence() takes those arguments in upside down order:

```
method setRecurrence(recurrence, startDate)
```

Many thanks to Serge for help, it was crutial! Unfortunately without reputation 15 I'm not able to give you any points :(

Comment: PS. Serge, do you know maybe how can we get the start date from CalendarEventSeries object? I'm affraid it is not possible, so I've done things in a little bit different way. But maybe you know some not documented back door? :)

Comment: it seems indeed that it is not possible, maybe you could post a new question on that subject and/or raise an enhancement request on the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list) if no interesting answer comes up.

Comment: This is exactly what I've done an hour ago :) Thanks for your help one more time.